# No access to volume after docker run -v

Tags: docker, google-cloud-build

The following command runs fine on my local machine.

```
docker run -it --rm --ulimit memlock=-1 \
            -v "$HOMEDIR/..":"/home/user/repo" \
            -w "/home/user/repo/linux" \
            ${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME} bash build.sh
```

Running it in a docker-in-docker evirionment (that means the mentioned docker command is executed in a container on google cloudbuild) is leading to two problems though:

1. Docker complains `The input device is not a tty`. My workaround: I simply used only `docker run -i --rm`.
2. Somehow the assigned volume and working directory on the container do not exist under the given path. But i checked them on the host system and they exist, but somehow do not make it until the container.

I thought also already about using `docker exec` but there i don't have the fancy `-v` options. I tried both, the docker run command with the -i and the -it flag on my local machine where it both runned fine. Anyway on cloudbuild i get the tty error when usind `-it` and the unacessible volume problem occurs when using `-i`.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with Cloud Build? Can you share your cloudbuild.yaml file? And why do not simply load the container in a step instead of wanted to run it inside a step?

Comment: If there are multiple Docker daemons involved, the left-hand side of the `-v` option will be interpreted in the target Docker's context.  So if this is a Docker-in-Docker setup, it will target the Docker-in-a-container filesystem, not the host filesystem; if it's a remote Docker then it will target the remote host's filesystem.  You can't use `-v` to send local files to a remote system.

Comment: What exactly is your multiple-Docker setup?  Do you have the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable set, and if so, to what?

Comment: @jo87casi Is your issue resolved? I don't see you responding to the above questions. Please help us know more by answering the questions above so that we can inspect more into this.

Comment: David Maze was right. I found a complete different workaround to solve my actual problem. Thanks anyway